# Notion API - Precision of last_edited_time and created_time

Tags: notion-api

I wrote an integration for google tasks for my wife, but in the end realized that Notion only has timestamps that are precise to the minute.
At first I was thinking timestamps were normal as here it says they can be compared to the millisecond:
https://developers.notion.com/changelog/dates-with-times-and-timezones-are-now-supported-on-database-date-filters

But here it says timestamps are only stored with precision to the minute:
https://developers.notion.com/changelog/last-edited-time-is-now-rounded-to-the-nearest-minute

In the API docs it needs to be mentioned in bold that create_time and last_edited_time are only precise to the minute (and that the times are rounded down).
https://developers.notion.com/reference/post-database-query-filter#date-filter-condition

Is this a way that Notion is restricting use of its Api?

Posting this on stack so that others can stumble upon it when they are searching as to why the API only works with minute precision for date filters.

Answer (score 1):

Filtering by timestamps was only recently added to the API in regards the original posts date:
https://developers.notion.com/changelog/filter-databases-by-timestamp-even-if-they-dont-have-a-timestamp-property

So hopefully more precise timestamp filter will be added.

Update:

Millisecond precision is shown as an example for the `last_edited_time` prop on pages: https://developers.notion.com/reference/page
But that is bad/incorrect example!
[image]
Last edited and created time properties are rounded to the nearest minute : https://developers.notion.com/changelog/last-edited-time-is-now-rounded-to-the-nearest-minute